# Why minimum weight in the minimum weight perfect matching?

Tags: error-correction, minimum-weight-perfect-matching

I am studying quantum decoding, especially for minimum weight perfect matching. I wonder after finding perfect matching (syndrome graph referred by sparse Blossom), why do we need to select minimum weight? Is there any specific reason for selecting minimum weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More weight corresponds to less probability. You're trying to guess the most likely error (max probability, min weight) so you want the min weight matching.

Comment: Would you please explain more ? Why more weigth corresponds to less probability?

Comment: @김동민 because w = -log(p / (1 - p)). When p is near 0, w increases as p decreases.

Comment: Where does the equation come from? paper? thesis?

Comment: I am sorry, what is p also?

Comment: @김동민 probability of error